# Using Kafka Security Manager for ACL for Schema Registry

Tags: apache-kafka, access-control, apache-kafka-security

I have a Kafka cluster running with Zookeeper, Confluent Schema registry and Kafka security manager(KSM). KSM, https://github.com/conduktor/kafka-security-manager, is software makes it easy to manager Kafka ACL with a csv file instead of using the command line tool.

The confluent schema registry let us store Avro schema for Kafka. It is currently open and I need to secured it. I want to give every user the READ or GET permission only. I am currently using kubernetes to deploy all the tools.

How can I do that with KSM? Where can I find examples?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Kafka ACLs don't apply to the Schema Registry, they would apply to the underlying `_schemas` topic, which you'd setup in the Registry's configuration

The API itself can be secured using TLS and HTTP Authentication

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/security/index.html

> give every user the READ or GET permission only.

I don't think you can lock down HTTP method level access to specific users, you'll likely need a proxy for this, but also without POST, there's no way to register topics...